# Is any apparent horizon a minimal surface?

Tags: general-relativity, mathematical-physics, black-holes, differential-geometry

I faced "any apparent horizon is a minimal surface", but I don't know how I can relate a physical concept ([apparent horizon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_horizon)) to pure mathematical concept ([minimal surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface)). How can I prove it?

Comment: Where did you encounter this statement?

Comment: The statement definitely needs a clarification. Minimal surface has mean curvature of zero, while apparent horizon can be curved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

The apparent horizon $\mathcal{H}$ is defined as the outer boundary of the region of $\Sigma$ (a hypersurface of spacetime with induced metric $h_{ab}$ and extrinsic curvature $K_{ab}$) which contains trapped or marginally trapped surfaces. $\mathcal{H}$ itself must be a marginally trapped surface, and thus it satisfies 
$$k+K^{ab}(h_{ab}-n_an_b)=0$$

where $k$ is the trace of the extrinsic curvature of $H$ as a submanifold of $\Sigma$ and $n^a$ is the unit outward normal to $H$ on $\Sigma$.

Now, **in the case of time symmetric data** (the extrinsic curvature $K_{ab}$ of $\Sigma$ has been set to zero) by above equation one can conclude $k=0$. Then minimal surface and apparent horizon coincide in the case of time symmetric data.